# How to use GRASS with HEC-RAS?

Tags: grass-gis, simulation

I am trying to use HEC-RAS for the flood modelling of my flood simulation. How do I use the text file output of HEC-RAS with the GRASS script r.inund.fluv?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to contact the authors of r.inund.fluv, see
https://svn.osgeo.org/grass/grass-addons/grass6/raster/r.inund.fluv/r.inund.fluv.html